# Handling URLs which have '@' for java.net.URI getUserInfo

Tags: java, groovy, uri

I have a string where a FTP URL is defined, and I want to parse the username and password details out of that string. For that I am using the getUserInfo method of  java.net.URI (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)...

```
 def userInfo = uri.getUserInfo()
 def username
 def password

   if(userInfo){
      def pos = userInfo.indexOf(":")
      if(pos >= 0){
          username = userInfo.substring(0, pos)
          password = userInfo.substring(pos+1)
   }    
 }
```

This code works fine except if the URL has a '@' in it like this..

```
 ftp://kirk@starfleet.com:spock123@enterprise.com/orders.txt
```

For a URL like this, a call to uri.getUserInfo() returns null.

Is there any way to handle such URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@` is not a valid character in a username or password in a URL. It has to be encoded. So your code will work if you write the URI like this:

`ftp://kirk%40starfleetcom:spock123@enterprisecom/orders.txt`

afaik, you should simply url-encode both username and password before you construct the URI:

`java.net.URLEncoder.encode(username)`